# D3 rotated text : smoothing in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, svg, d3.js

I've created a D3 pie chart and have rotated the text labels to flow radially outward. This looks good on IE, but unfortunately in Chrome the text looks horrible. CSS webkit font smoothing tricks don't seem to work. I'm guessing this needs to be done in SVG/D3 land...? Chrome just doesn't want to cooperate.

The full code is at this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mn5bT/2/

I append the text labels in this manner:

```
g.append("text")
.attr("transform", function(d) {
var c = arc.centroid(d),
    x = c[0],
    y = c[1],
    h = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y); // pythagorean theorem
    flipAngle = d.endAngle > Math.PI;
    angleOffset = flipAngle? 90:-90;
    return "translate(" + (x/h * radius) +  ',' + (y/h * radius) +  ")" +
            "rotate(" + (angleOffset + 180*(d.endAngle + d.startAngle)/2/Math.PI) + ")";
})
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
    // are we past the center?
    return (d.endAngle + d.startAngle)/2 > Math.PI ? "end" : "start";
})
.text(function(d) { return d.data.value.campus; });
```

Comment: Is this on windows? On linux Chrome v31.0.1650.8-dev the text labels in http://jsfiddle.net/mn5bT/2/ are drawn smoothly (with antialiasing). There is some wonkiness with the baseline alignment though (separate issue).

Comment: Yes the text jagginess I see is with Chrome 30.0.1599.69m running on Win8. Also tried 32.0.1664.3 dev-m Aura and the jagginess is still there. Looks like a Chrome/Win specific bug.

Comment: I think http://crbug.com/25541 might be the thing for you.

Comment: Wow that's a long-running thread! Looks like the fix has been put in as a "runtime enabled feature", but I haven't figured out what flag enables it.  chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-webkit-feaures

Answer (score 2):

You can try to "hand anti-alias" your text by adding a blur filter. It looks a little better on Chrome.

```
var defs = svg.append("defs");
var filter = defs.append("filter")
    .attr("id", "drop")
    .attr("height", "130%");

filter.append("feGaussianBlur")
    .attr("in", "SourceGraphic")
    .attr("stdDeviation", .5)
    .attr("result", "blur");

filter.append("feOffset")
    .attr("in", "blur")
    .attr("dx", 0)
    .attr("dy", 0)
    .attr("result", "offsetBlur");

var feMerge = filter.append("feMerge");

feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
    .attr("in", "offsetBlur")
feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
    .attr("in", "SourceGraphic");
```

Thanks to [cpbotha's original example](http://bl.ocks.org/cpbotha/5200394). live fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ey8Xp/

Comment: Note that this will probably make the text look less crisp when that bug gets fixed.

Comment: Yes, this is a total hack

Comment: Nice one Michael. Hack or not, it does the job. I wouldn't have been able to figure this out myself. Would you mind sharing a link on how to make filters?
  Has the text jagginess been reported officially as a bug, and is anyone at Google working on it?

Comment: http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/svg/elements/filter is the main webplatform page. I did a filter tutorial for html5devconf that you can read here: http://www.slideshare.net/mullany1/svg-filters-html5-devconf-apr-2013

Answer (score 1):

You can set special properties for SVG text, in particular [`text-rendering`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-rendering) should be of interest. Your example looks much better to me when I add

```
text {
  text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
}
```

to the CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I added that to the CSS but it still looks bad in Chrome 30.0.  For a comparison, try viewing it in IE for how smooth it should look.

Comment: It may be the case that it doesn't work well in that particular version of Chrome. You can also try some of the other values to see if that improves it.

Comment: This solution greatly improves rendering in Firefox. IE already looks great by default. But chrome 56 doesn't seem to react to this at all. :(

Answer (score 0):

From [Improving font rendering with CSS](https://medium.com/@MateMarschalko/improving-font-rendering-with-css-3383fc358cbc)

> I did some research and it turned out that Windows doesn’t apply much
>   anti-aliasing to text in most cases. Good news is that in Microsoft’s
>   latest browsers things actually look quite good: font rendering is
>   much much better compared to Chrome and Firefox.